# DOCX to PDF converter program

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm making a doc to pdf converter program, and i have occured an error as below:
[image: Error]

Im an begginer in programming and i dont know how to fix it, below i paste python code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request, render_template, redirect, url_for, send_file
import os
from typing import Tuple
from docx2pdf import convert
#from tkinter import Tk,messagebox
#from tkinter import _tkinter
UPLOADER_FOLDER = ''
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOADER_FOLDER'] = UPLOADER_FOLDER

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":
        def docx2pdf(input_file: str, output_file: str, pages: Tuple = None):
           if pages:
               pages = [int(i) for i in list(pages) if i.isnumeric()]

           result = convert(docx_file=input_file, pdf_file=output_file, pages=pages)
           summary = {
               "File": input_file, "Pages": str(pages), "Output File": output_file
            }

           print("\n".join("{}:{}".format(i, j) for i, j in summary.items()))
           return result
        file = request.files['filename']
        if file.filename!= '':
           file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOADER_FOLDER'], file.filename))
           input_file = file.filename
           output_file = r"hello.pdf"
           docx2pdf(input_file, output_file)
           pdf = input_file.split(".")[0]+".pdf"
           print(pdf)
           lis=pdf.replace(" ", "=")
           return render_template("docx.html", variable=lis)
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route('/docx', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def docx():
    if request.method=="POST":
        lis = request.form.get('filename', None)
        lis = lis.replace("=", " ")
        return send_file(lis, as_attachment=True)
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

There are two templates called index.html and docx.html in Templates directory, this is how it looks in Pycharm:

[image: Program structure]

Does anyone have an idea where i made an mistake? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing parameters into the `convert` method like this:

```
result = convert(docx_file=input_file, pdf_file=output_file, pages=pages)
```

But the docx2pdf `convert` method is defined like this:

```
def convert(input_path, output_path=None, keep_active=False):
```

as you can see, there is no parameter called `docx_file`, so you get the error that this parameter was unexpected. To fix this, either get rid of the names altogether:

```
result = convert(input_file, output_file)
```

or use the correct parameter names:

```
result = convert(input_path=input_file, output_path=output_file)
```

I also see that you have passed a variable called `pages`. I'm not familiar with this library so I can't be 100% sure, but I didn't find a `convert` function with a parameter called pages anywhere.

Since you are in PyCharm, right click on the `convert` function and select Go to -> Declaration to see the method. You should be able to see what the function does. There is limited documentation on this library so you will have to rely on reading the code to understand.

Comment: I did as You recommended and it works perfectly. Thank You!

Comment: It worked well for couple of tries but now there is an error like this "File not found:

  File "C:\Users\mateu\PycharmProjects\doc_pdf\app.py", line 44, in docx
    return send_file(lis, as_attachment=True)

Comment: I'm guessing that the file whos name you are POSTing to the endpoint doesn't exist. Since you are in PyCharm, run the application in debug mode and place a breakpoint on the line to figure out what is going on (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/part-1-debugging-python-code.html#start-debugger-session). Additionally, I see that this is not related to this question since we are talking about two different endpoints here, so if you can't figure it out with the debugger, please open another question.